# Dropdown Submenu HTML and CSS (shaking)

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I need to create a very simple responsive menu with submenu. The problem that I currently have is that my submenu "shakes", and I can't figure out why.

Thanks!

This is my HTML

```
<header>
    <a href="inicio.html" id="logo">
    </a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li><a href="#">Soluciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

This is my CSS:

```
header {
background-color: #102a42;
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #102a42 0%, #171c31 100%);
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 100; 
}

#logo {
margin: 20px;
float: left;
width: 230px;
height: 46px;
background: url(../images/logo-header.png) no-repeat center;
display: block;
}

nav {
float: right;
padding: 10px 20px 0 0;
}

#menu-icon {
display: hidden;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: url(../images/menu-icon.png) center;
}


ul{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1em;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

li a {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1em;
}

li a:hover {
color: #00BFA1;
}


li ul {
display: none;
}

li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}


li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 200px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help, I need to solve this issue by today! :) I haven't been able to upload my site anywhere just yet, so I don't have a way to show you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

On your last CSS rule you can change instead the hovering on the anchor tag into the li and that way it won't be jumping. Another way is to add padding to your anchor so then you can target the hover on the anchor. Hope this helps.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22zc7qk3/2/)

```css
header {
background-color: #102a42;
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #102a42 0%, #171c31 100%);
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 100; 
}

#logo {
margin: 20px;
float: left;
width: 230px;
height: 46px;
background: url(../images/logo-header.png) no-repeat center;
display: block;
}

nav {
float: right;
padding: 10px 20px 0 0;
}

#menu-icon {
display: hidden;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: url(../images/menu-icon.png) center;
}


ul{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1em;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

li a {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1em;
}

li a:hover {
color: #00BFA1;
}


li ul {
display: none;
}

li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}


li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 200px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li:hover a + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="inicio.html" id="logo">
    </a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li><a href="#">Soluciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It doesn't shake anymore. However, my submenu text "Sub 1", is aligned to the right. Here is a screenshot: snag.gy/QhCJOc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When you show `.hidden`, the `a` tag is shifting to the left and the `.hidden` element appears beneath the `a` tag. As soon as your hover rule take effect you are no longer hovering over `a` or `.hidden` so it hides, then you are hovering so the cycle repeats. Target the containing `li`'s hover state instead of the one for the `a` tag.

```css
header {
background-color: #102a42;
background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #102a42 0%, #171c31 100%);
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 100; 
}

#logo {
margin: 20px;
float: left;
width: 230px;
height: 46px;
background: url(../images/logo-header.png) no-repeat center;
display: block;
}

nav {
float: right;
padding: 10px 20px 0 0;
}

#menu-icon {
display: hidden;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: url(../images/menu-icon.png) center;
}


ul{
list-style: none;
font-size: 1em;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

li a {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1em;
}

li a:hover {
color: #00BFA1;
}


li ul {
display: none;
}

li ul li {
display: block;
float: none;
}


li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 200px;
padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li:hover a + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="inicio.html" id="logo">
    </a>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Productos</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li><a href="#">Soluciones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It doesn't shake anymore. However, my submenu text "Sub 1", is aligned to the right. Here is a screenshot: https://snag.gy/QhCJOc.jpg

Comment: The positioning is resulting from padding. `.hidden` has 40px padding on the left and the child `li` has 10px on all sides.

Comment: Thanks @JasonB I need the 10px padding for the li.  But I still can't make the submenu item to look the way it should (without any aligned to the left, just like the menu item). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my submenu has solved the problem

```js
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
    title: "Menu",
    breakpoint: 768,
    format: "multitoggle"
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #102a42;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #00bfa1;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #102a42;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #00bfa1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen li:hover > ul > li {
  height: auto;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #00bfa1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 17px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  top: 23px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  background: #00bfa1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  top: 23px;
  background: #00bfa1;
  width: 15px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
  background: #0b1d2d;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 19px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:after {
  top: 15px;
  right: 13px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  background: #00bfa1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul .submenu-button:before {
  top: 12px;
  right: 16px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- MenuMaker Plugin -->
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-circle-o"></i> Nosotros</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-navicon"></i> Productos</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Categoría 1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.1.1</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.1.2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.1.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Categoría 2</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 2.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 2.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Categoría 3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 3.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 3.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">Categoría 4</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 4.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 4.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Categoría 4.3</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o"></i> Soluciones</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Servicios</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```